# Property object assignment

Tags: python, properties, getter-setter

I have been reading some examples of using getter and setter via Python `property` object and saw two different implementations but I could not tell what's the difference.

assigning to private variable in `__init__`:

```
class Alphabet:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
 
    # getting the values
    def getValue(self):
        print('Getting value')
        return self._value
 
    # setting the values
    def setValue(self, value):
        print('Setting value to ' + value)
        self._value = value
 
    # deleting the values
    def delValue(self):
        print('Deleting value')
        del self._value
 
    value = property(getValue, setValue,
                     delValue, )
```

assigning to property object in `__init__`:

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature=0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    # getter
    def get_temperature(self):
        print("Getting value...")
        return self._temperature

    # setter
    def set_temperature(self, value):
        print("Setting value...")
        if value < -273.15:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273.15 is not possible")
        self._temperature = value

    # creating a property object
    temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)
```

Comment: Python does not have private variables.

Comment: `self.temperature = temperature` is actually `self.set_temperature(temperature)`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any real difference between your two examples, except for the default value in `__init__`.

Comment: the second possibility is to use the `property`-decorator approach... your code snapshots are equivalents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Alphabet.__init__`, you don't have the effect of the setter but in `Celsius.__init__` you have.

In other words in `Celsius.__init__`, you're setting the value of your private variable(you called it, they are not private by that meaning in other languages) through the setter, but in `Alphabet.__init__` you're setting it directly.

So if you have any validation in your setter, it's not gonna work while you *instantiating* your class in `Alphabet`, but it will in `Celsius`.

Comment: Thank you but instantiating the Alphabet class with x = Alphabet('test') seems to call the setter too .So in fact is it setting the same value variable two times ? once in init and then via setter ?

Comment: @Amir No it doesn't call setter, if it does, you would see the result of `print('Setting value to ' + value)` in the output.

Comment: Yes your are right i was testing following : x = Alphabet('test')
print(x.value)
x.value = 'testest'
print(x.value) . so when instantiating  the setter is not called but when assigning to object attribute its called . im still little confused how it actually works.

Comment: @Amir Yes that should work fine. Look, you have a property(which has setter) named `value` in your class, so when you say `x.value = 'testest'`, you're calling the setter. That's it. But now look at `__init__`, you didn't say `self.value = value`. instead you wrote `self._value = value`. What is `_value`? it is not your property, `value` is your property, so don't expect to see setter call when you say `self._value = value`. That `_value` is just a normal instance attribute which your setter use it as the underlying attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the program that creates that objects you will see the difference:

```
Celsius(10) # prints Setting value
Alphabet(10) # prints nothing
```

So `Celsius` version just use the setter during the `__init__` (which has a sense if you have some logic behind setting attribute value). And that's it, there are no more differences.

Comment: Note that in `Celsius` if one were to assign a value less than `-273.15` directly in `__init__` no exception would be raised, whereas using `set_temperature` does make that a possibility.